# Does a clock lose energy by changing reference frame?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, energy, time-dilation

If I see a clock running more slowly than normal in daily life I assume it is losing energy (e.g. due to low battery)

In Special Relativity a clock which moves quickly runs more slowly and In General Relativity a clock getting closer to a center of gravity also runs more slowly

From my perspective on Earth the clock appears to lose energy in these situations

Does the clock actually lose energy?

Comment: If my heart beats slower am I losing energy?

Comment: Why would a low battery make a clock run slower?

Comment: @J.Murray Capacitor charges more slowly in clocks with pulsed second hands, and gears turn more slowly in motorized movement.

Comment: @BillN Good answer to a silly question, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a way, *and* in what I'd think you'd *really* want to ask - **yes**.

The first part of this answer requires clearing up a slight misconception about how the battery-powered clock slows down or, perhaps better, we should say *isolating the most proximate cause* of the slowing-down of the battery-powered clock. In fact, the clock is "losing energy" all the time, as the energy in the battery is being expended, and used up (ultimately, turning into tiny bits of heat and sound) to move the clock hands, but it does not *noticeably* slow down until the accessible energy supply in the battery is almost gone. The reason this happens is due more to the specifics of how batteries operate as energy sources, and not all energy sources have this property (e.g. when a gas-powered car runs out of gas, that's it - it just quits), and isn't relevant here.

What *is* relevant here is that the slowing-down of the clock represents a decrease in the **power** - the *rate* of energy *delivery* to the motor turning the clock hands. The rate of energy delivery decreases and so the motor can't turn as fast since it doesn't receive energy fast enough to fight the losses from internal friction that must occur when the hand is rotating with a given speed, and as a result, the clock hands slow down to a speed where that those losses are suitably balanced.

In other words, the question should first be more properly phrased as "*Does a clock **lose power** by changing its reference frame?*", where "power" means "rate of energy conversion of stored energy in the battery into mechanical energy", to better isolate what I think you're really after as that's what the phenomenon of slowing at the end of battery life amounts to physically, even though it in turn is caused *secondarily* by the actual draining of energy.

And guess what - in both SR and GR, thanks to **time dilation**, indeed, that answer *is* yes: *the power that the outside observer registers the battery as delivering to the hands and the motor decreases*. Since time is slowed down, *everything* slows down and that means also the process of energy transfer. If the battery delivers, say, one milliwatt - one millijoule in one second - in its own rest frame, and one of "its" seconds takes two "outside" seconds to elapse, then the outside observer will account the battery power as having dropped to 0.5 milliwatts, seeing that same millijoule's delivery to the motor stretched out over two seconds instead of one. Moreover, due to the principle of relativity, because the same laws of physics that imply the hands must slow down when the battery power falls when in your local rest frame must hold in others, then it is equally "valid" in a sense to attribute (though not sure if *all* can be) the slowing in this case precisely to this reduction in power output from the battery!

Comment: @The_Sympathizer be aware that the power delivered by the battery does not actually decrease in this scenario. Power transforms as the timelike component of the four force. In the battery’s frame the four force is $(P’,0)$ and in the moving frame the four force is $(\gamma P’, \gamma P’ v)=(\gamma P, \gamma f)$ so $P’=P$ in the case where there is no force in the rest frame.

Answer (score 6):

> Does the clock actually lose energy?

No.

Your reasoning is incorrect. You have noticed “if A then B” where A is “a clock has lost most of its energy” and B is “the clock runs slowly”. But “if A then B” does not imply “if B then A”.

It is incorrect to conclude that if a clock runs slow then it has lost energy.

Answer (score 4):

No, the source of energy for the operation of the clock is not depleted as a consequence of a change in reference frame. In its rest frame the clock is continuing to run at its normal rate.

Answer (score 1):

Let me put that question in terms of the twin scenario.

Let there be two clocks, one remaining at rest, the other is sent on a relativistic journey. Let's say the clock's internal energy source can power the clock for exactly 5 years. Let's call that internal energy source a battery.

Let the relativistic journey be such that on rejoining the resting clock has counted 5 years, and that the traveling clock is seen to have counted 3 years of elapsed proper time. The battery of traveler is examined, and it is seen to have 40% charge remaining. The resting clock, having counted 5 years, has a depleted battery.

That is: during all of this the *energy usage per year* has been the same for both clocks.

For both clocks the internal physics remains the same. It's not that the traveling clock is shifted to some lower energy consumption regime. It is about the amount of proper time itself. When the clocks rejoin then for the traveling clock less proper time has elapsed.

This extends to the gravitational time dilation as described by General Relativity. If the traveling clock orbits for a while in a deep gravity well, such that on rejoining the traveling clock is seen to have counted less proper time, then the energy usage per year of proper time is not changed.

(If you are not familiar with the expression 'proper time' I recommend that you look it up. It is a standard expression, widely used.)

(The reason I moved to the twin scenario: if you are receiving information about a clock that is far away you have to correct for transmission delay, and if there is a relative velocity you have to take that into account also. In the twin scenario you compare the clocks only when the clocks are *together*; at the start and at the end. That eliminiates all ambiguity.)

Answer (score 1):

In your observer frame, you will see the clock run slower in a dilated time frame, but it will run slower for a longer time before the battery dies. In other words, the hands will spin around the same amount of revolutions before the battery dies in any frame. In the clock's frame, nothing has changed. You could see a clock at near c barely moving for hundreds of your years.

Answer (score 1):

Clocks in "normal life" are not some battery on a motor as that would be way too unprecise: clocks were already more precise in the middle ages by using some kind of escapement tied to an oscillator.  Older electrical clocks basically were wind-up clocks with a mechanical escapement that regularly wound themselves up for a period of time short compared to the energy reserves of normal wind-up clocks using either a spring or weights as energy source.  Modern quartz clocks use a quartz as oscillator and have electric "escapement" as well as electric "gears" and use a stepped motor for driving the seconds hand (and via gears, the rest).  When that motor is not provided enough energy for moving the hands reliably, the clock loses time because of the seconds hand missing beats.  When the clock finally stops, it tends to be at about 10 to 9 when the weight of the hands is heaviest.

What I am getting at is that the time-keeping of a clock has nothing whatsoever to do with the battery.  The battery does not determine the speed of the clock but rather when it starts failing.

Now all physical processes that could be used for time-keeping are subject to special/general relativity.  All oscillators you could use for time-keeping, mechanical or electrical or electromagnetical or chemical, are "broken" with the same results when moving, so you can just equivalently say that time is changed.  This includes the chemicals being used up in the battery in response to the currents keeping the clock going.  Depending on how you measure the energy of the battery, its value may be minusculely different while the battery is seen moving, but as the clock comes to rest again, the amount of energy loss in the battery will correspond to what the clock shows. However, the *acceleration* and deceleration phases will put forces on the clock that may cause more battery drain, so you should keep them short compared to the unaccelerated travel times.  Basically, stick with special rather than general relativity effects as much as you can or things get muddier.

Answer (score 1):

The slowing of clocks has nothing to do with energy loss.  Indeed in the better textbooks and even on WP the clocks are idealized [light clocks](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_clock) with no battery or weights at all.  Moreover, a clock “does not change frame” since (synchronized) clocks are a feature of the coordinate system and the reference frame.